# Try to understand normalizr's schema.entity VS Array and Object

Tags: normalizr

All:

I am trying to understand the relationship between Entity Array and Object:

1. Are they just different format to describe diff structure of data? Or Entity is quite diff from the rest two?
2. The normalized data result has a structure like {result:,entities:}, **are the data structures only defined with schema.Entity put inside entities** or so can schema.Array and Object? When I define a schema only use Object and Array, it seems nothing put in entities, I am not sure if it is my schema def fault or this is how normalizr work?
3. If only schema.Entity() defined data can put into entities, then how can I put an data array into it, something like {0:.., 1:..,2:,}?

For exmaple, I have data like:

```
var data = [
    {
        id:"0",
        items:[
            {
                id: "0",
                data: {name:"data-0-0"}
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                data: {name:"data-0-1"}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id:"1",
        items:[
            {
                id: "0",
                data: {name:"data-1-0"}
            },
            {
                id: "1",
                data: {name:"data-1-1"}
            }
        ]
    }
]

const normalizedData = normalize(data, [{items:[{data:{}}]}]);

And the normalized data is like:

{
    "entities": {},
    "result": {
        "0": {
            "id": "0",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "data": {
                        "name": "data-1-0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question:** *Are they just different format to describe diff structure of data? Or Entity is quite diff from the rest two?*

**Answer:** Yes. An `Entity` is a singular object that has a unique identifier associated with it. `Array` and `Object` are more generic structures that can't be uniquely identified. In your case, it looks like you only need to use `Array` and `Entity` for the data you're describing.

**Question:** *Are the data structures only defined with schema? Entity put inside entities?*

**Answer:** Yes.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to #3, thanks for help